# overflow + max-height bug ie8 (compatibility mode) or ie7 in ie tester

Tags: css, xhtml

Here is the page:

http://jerenovici.net/index.php?option=com_ai&view=repertoires&Itemid=31

The menu on the right is using a mootools script for the animation.

When you open an element the white box does not take 100% of the space in ie8 (compatibility mode) or ie7 in ie tester

Tested in google chrome, ie8, firefox, and safari and no isssues with other browsers. the result is as wanted. any idea why in ie7 I get this error and how can I fix it? I've noticed for it to take full space in ie7 I must remove the max-height and the overflow: auto in my css... but I want to keep theses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't quickly figure out exactly *why* it happens (complex page), but I did find a very nasty "quick fix":

In `/modules/mod_repertoiremenu/mod_repertoiremenu.js`, underneath this line:

```
collapsibles[i] = collapsible;
```

Add this:

```
if (Browser.Engine.trident5) { //If IE7, fix menu
    list[i].setStyle('margin-left', '-16px');
}
```

It's better than it was, right?

Comment: worked! ive been trying css fixes, never tryied any javascript fixes thanks. this will do for now :)